# Saving Mysql query "show status" into txt file

Tags: mysql

How to save mysql query 'SHOW STATUS' into txt file. I used -->

MySQL -u root -p -e "SHOW STATUS;" > NAME.txt  --> but it did not work.

Comment: Please use the tags to format the command properly

Answer (score 1):

I just created a command file called `c:\dev\in.txt` and dump results to `c:\dev\out21.txt` to illustrate this.

`in.txt` contains 1 line with a newline at end:

```
show status;
```

### run mysql with in and out

```
mysql -uUserName -p <c:\dev\in.txt >c:\dev\out21.txt
```

or

```
mysql -uUserName -p < /path/to/in.txt >/path/to/out21.txt
```

### Examine c:\dev\out21.txt (or /path/to/out21.txt)

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 4
Aborted_connects        64
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use        0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use      0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
...
...
...
```